# Having 'and' command inside list comprehension

Tags: python, pathlib

I do not understand what this source code does on line 3, `res = [...];` I tried to understand by testing out in python console with dummy variables and in the same syntax format like `res = ['raj' / 'esh'];` it gives error; if tested with `res = ['raj' and 'esh'];` I always return the second string `'esh'`, so I'm confused why use 'and' in the line. The syntax p/o also confuses me.

```
def _get_files(parent, p, f, extensions):
    p = Path(p)  #.relative_to(parent)
    res = [p/o for o in f if not o.startswith('.')
           and (extensions is None or f'.{o.split(".")[-1].lower()}' in extensions)]
    return res
```

Argument `p` parsed is file path (string), argument f parsed is `f = [o.name for o in os.scandir(path) if o.is_file()]`; where path in this syntax line is file path. Could I get any help in understanding line 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`['raj' and 'esh']` is a one-element array, whose sole element is the result of `'raj'` and `'esh'`; `and` will evaluate to the first operand if falsy, and second operand otherwise. Since the first operand is not falsy, you get `'esh'`.

The line in the code is not a simple array, it is a *comprehension* - basically a short way to write a loop that constructs an array. The general syntax of a comprehension is

```
[x for y in z if p]
```

where `y` will loop over all elements of the iterable `z`, check if `p` is true, and if it is, add `x` to the result. In your case, the condition (`p`) is

```
not o.startswith('.')
and
(extensions is None or f'.{o.split(".")[-1].lower()}' in extensions)
```

For each element `o` of `f` (presumably an iterable of filenames), if this criterion is true, the result list will gain an element which consists of the concatenation of the path `p` with the filename `o` (`/` being a natural, if surprising at first sight, concatenation operator for paths.)

The problem is compounded by bad naming exhibited in the snippet. Consider this rewrite:

```
def _hidden(filename):
    return filename.startswith('.')

def _extension(filename):
    return '.' + filename.split(".")[-1].lower()

def _extension_ok(filename, allowed_extensions=None):
    return allowed_extensions is None
           or _extension(filename) in allowed_extensions

def _get_files(parent, path, filenames, allowed_extensions=None):
    path = Path(path)
    good_paths = [path/filename for filename in filenames
                  if not _hidden(filename)
                     and _extension_ok(filename, allowed_extensions)]
    return good_paths
```

Now this reads almost like English, and is very clear about what it's doing (the only dodgy bit being `path/filename`, and almost anyone could guess what that might be just by analogy to UNIX paths).

Comment: Thank you!! I wasn't able to figure out it's an concatenation operator.

Comment: Yeah, but let me reiterate, it is _just_ for `Path` objects. Reading about [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) should clarify.

Answer (score 1):

It's a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

```
res = [p/o for o in f if not o.startswith('.')
       and (extensions is None or f'.{o.split(".")[-1].lower()}' in extensions)]
```

Is a syntactic shorthand for

```
res = []
for o in f:
    if not o.startswith('.') and (extensions is None or f'.{o.split(".")[-1].lower()}' in extensions):
        res.append(p/o)
```

Comment: Why one earth though someone thought that `in` check needed to be put in an f-string though... *sighs*